# Wrap specific divs Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code

```html
<div class="superdiv">
  <div class="nicediv"></div>
  <div class="extradiv"></div>
  <div class="extradiv"></div>
  <div class="extradiv"></div>
</div>
 <div class="superdiv">
  <div class="nicediv"></div>
  <div class="extradiv"></div>
  <div class="extradiv"></div>
  <div class="extradiv"></div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap all the `.extradiv` into a `div`.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
$(".superdiv").each(function(){
    $(this).children(".extradiv").wrapAll("<div/>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wrapAll()` to wrap the selected elements in the provided HTML. Given your updated HTML, you will also need to loop over the `.superdiv` elements and wrap only the `.extradiv` within each instance. Try this:

```js
$('.superdiv').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.extradiv').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="superdiv">
  <div class="nicediv">nicediv</div>
  <div class="extradiv">extradiv</div>
  <div class="extradiv">extradiv</div>
  <div class="extradiv">extradiv</div>
</div>
 <div class="superdiv">
  <div class="nicediv">nicediv</div>
  <div class="extradiv">extradiv</div>
  <div class="extradiv">extradiv</div>
  <div class="extradiv">extradiv</div>
</div>
```